# Skype doesn't appear in the indicator zone

Tags: indicator, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the Skype status icon back? (on panel/tray)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151112/how-do-i-get-the-skype-status-icon-back-on-panel-tray)

I recently switched over to Ubuntu 11.10 x64 and when I installed Skype and launched it I noticed that it doesn't appear in the indicator zone. I tried installing Skype Wrapper so that it could appear in the messaging menu but it doesn't show up there either, while Skype Wrapper tells me that everything is fine. How can I fix this?