# How do I get the Skype status icon back? (on panel/tray)

Tags: unity, indicator, panel, skype, statusbar

I installed Skype 4.0 following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/150868/61555). However my little Skype icon in the unity status bar (in the top right corner with clock, volume, etc.) is gone. How do I get it back?