# Skype 4 does not shows icon in the panel

Tags: icons, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skype 4.0: How can I get the Skype status panel/tray icon back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151112/skype-4-0-how-can-i-get-the-skype-status-panel-tray-icon-back)

I installed Skype 4 in Ubuntu and now it does not show its icon in the top panel like it did:

[http://i.imgur.com/XjZVf.png](https://i.imgur.com/XjZVf.png)

This is how it looks now:

[http://i.imgur.com/ytQwd.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/ytQwd.jpg)

Is there a way to enable skype icon in the panel?