# How to display the status icon of skype

Tags: unity, indicator, skype, panel, statusbar

How do I get the Skype status icon on the main bar of ubuntu?

I've tried to follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151112/how-do-i-get-the-skype-status-icon-back-on-panel-tray), but it wouldn't work. I don't have the `panel` menus. So, I'm here looking for another way to proceed.

ANy brilliant suggestion, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, installing the following package fixed it for me: sni-qt:i386

To do that open up a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Worked in Ubuntu 13.10, 14.04 and 16.04

Comment: Still the solution for 16.04 (sad to know the problem persits).