# How can I fix the Skype (and the Franz) tray icon not showing up properly?

Tags: skype, 16.10, system-tray, franz

**System specifications:**

- Ubuntu 16.10 Unity
- skype 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
- Franz Version: 4.0.4 Build: 40 Release: 1.3.1 / linux / x64
- skype-bin:i386 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
- sni-qt 0.2.7+15.10.20150729-0ubuntu1
- sni-qt:i386 0.2.7+15.10.20150729-0ubuntu1

**Other observations:**

Besides Skype, the same propblem occurs with [Franz](http://meetfranz.com/).

**Screenshots:**

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Install `sni-qt` package `sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386` and restart skype.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `sni-qt` is already installed. I updated my question.

Comment: And the problem occurs with `Franz` as well.

Comment: and did you whitelist the indicators as also described [here?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151112/how-do-i-get-the-skype-status-icon-back-on-panel-tray/151118#151118) Just an FYI, but stating that you've applied half an answer isn't likely to get your post re-opened as a different issue.

Comment: @ElderGeek sorry about that! I don't have the entries mentioned in the described answer. See [this](http://i.imgur.com/8lkwrwR.png).

Comment: While I look into this, please [edit] all this important information into your question so we don't all have to plow through the comments in an attempt to find you an answer. thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Thank you so much @ElderGeek! I hope my question satisfies now.

Comment: @orschiro  I've written an answer tested under 16.10 here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/456950/system-tray-icons-disappeared-after-upgrading-ubuntu/848369#848369

Answer (score 2):

To have Skype tray icon displayed install `sni-qt` package:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Comment: `sni-qt:i386 is already the newest version (0.2.7+15.10.20150729-0ubuntu1).`

Comment: @orschiro thats strange, In my opinion forget about the Skype tray icon and use [skype-wrapper](https://launchpad.net/~skype-wrapper/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) that will fully integrate Skype into the messaging menu (unread messages, pop-up notifications, etc.) that will nicely integrate Skype into your messaging menu, and thus there's no need to have its icon in the tray.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I need to be able to do phone calls to non-Skype contacts, however.

Comment: @orshiro Here's a tested working answer for Ubuntu 16.10 I just wrote. http://askubuntu.com/questions/456950/system-tray-icons-disappeared-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04/848369#848369